# Mariadb Won't Change CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS from latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, vagrant, mariadb

I'm using 5.5.64-MariaDB MariaDB Server.  I cannot for the life of me change the character_set_results to utf8.  I tried `ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` I also tried `SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = utf8mb4;
SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = utf8mb4;`

Then I went into my.cnf and it looks like this

```
[mysqld]
datadir                         = /var/database/db
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
query_cache_size                = 16M
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
character_set_server   = utf8mb4
collation_server       = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_database: utf8mb4
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_server: utf8mb4
```

After changing my.cnf I restarted mariadb and that was successful.

When I run `mysqladmin -u root -p var | grep -E 'character|collation' | tr -s ' '` I get this

```
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ mysqladmin -u root -p var | grep -E 'character|collation' | tr -s ' '
Enter password:
| character_set_client | latin1 |
| character_set_connection | latin1 |
| character_set_database | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results | latin1 |
| character_set_server | latin1 |
| character_set_system | utf8 |
| character_sets_dir | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server | latin1_swedish_ci |
```

How can I change the CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS?  I also tried `SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = utf8mb4;` and `SET character_set_results = utf8mb4;` But it keeps getting reset back to latin1 when I run my java integration tests.  I greped my project and latin1 is no where to be found.  I have no idea why it keeps getting reset to latin1 and how I can change it to utf8.  Any ideas?  I don't feel like upgrading mariadb to 10.X would help but if someone ran into this problem and that was the solution I will give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

The global settings are correct, however when a client connects to the server the client forces the server to change the character set (by default client tools and Connector/C are using latin1).

The output from mysqladmin shows session variables which changed to latin1, since during connection handshake mysqladmin told the server to use latin1.

mysqladmin doesn't read values from [mysqld], but from [mysql],[client] and [mysqladmin] groups.

If you want to force all clients to use utf8mb4 you can do this in the [mysqld] section:

e.g.
`init_connect=set names utf8mb4`

or 
`skip-character-set-client-handshake`.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER DATABASE` and `ALTER TABLE` only change the *default* settings.

To convert all the string columns in one table to utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO utf8mb4;
```

To convert one column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col_name ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ...;
```

where the ... is any other things, such as `VARCHAR(...)` and `NOT NULL`.

Caution:  These assume that the encoding in the columns matched the declaration (eg, latin1).  If not, the above alters will make things worse.

Properly done, one-byte accented latin1 letters will turn into the corresponding 2-byte utf8mb4 letters.

Some cases:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Since you are still on 5.5, there are other issues you may encounter if you have `VARCHAR(255)` (or anything over 191).  See:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: Please don't promote `utf8` in MySQL. UTF-8 is not limited to 2 bytes. This a lie. Only legacy MySQL thinks that it is. Read (and share) this: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434 Use `utf8mb4`, always.